# Problem about almost everywhere convergence in measure theory

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

I am having trouble with the following problem

> Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ a measure space where $\mu (X)<\infty.$  Let $f,f_n:X \to \mathbb{C}$ be measurable. Set $A_n=\{ |f_n-f|\geq a_n\}$ where $a_n>0$ and $a_n \to 0$. Show that if $\sum_n \mu (A_n)<\infty,$ then  $f_n\xrightarrow{a.e.} f.$

I've been trying a lot this problem. For example, I tried to show that $\mu (\{f_n \nrightarrow f\})<\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ using facts as $\mu(A_n) \to 0$ (because the series is convergent) and even asumming that $(a_n)$ could be taken strictly decrasing.
In my "closer" attempt I showed that every $x \in \{f_n \nrightarrow f\}$ is contained in infinitely many of the sets $A_n$. But at the end, it doesn't worked.

At every attempt I made, I though "I'm very very close to the solution"... but something failed.

Could you please help me solving this problem?

Comment: Same question but converging a.e. to $0$ instead of $f$ in general. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222384/trying-to-do-a-measure-theory-proof-concerning-almost-everywhere-convergence?rq=1

Comment: Whenever you see the assumption that a series of measures, $\sum\mu(A_n)$, is finite, you should always think of the Borel-Cantelli lemma which says that $\mu(\limsup A_n):= \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k\geq n}A_k\right)=0$ (the proof is really short, as the answer below shows). I can't tell you the number of times this innocent looking lemma has solved problems for me

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you! However, I hadn't seen Borel-Cantelli's lemma in the book that I am reading now  (that lemma is stated some chapters after the current problem). So I can't use it. However, thank you very much for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First observe that the set where $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ is measurable and it can be written as $A:=\{f_n\not\to f\}=\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n\ge k}A_n.$

Now note that showing $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere is equivalent to showing that $A$ has measure $0.$  To do this, we first observe that
$$\mu(A)\le \mu(\bigcup_{n\ge k}A_n)\le \sum_{n\ge k}A_n.$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$ is finite, by choosing $k$ large, we can make $\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$ arbitrarily small. It follows that $\mu(A)=0.$